# very strange thing in cake php... converting multiple value to string

Tags: php, cakephp

i am using below query ,its converting all things to string

```
$idsv =$_GET['ids'];
$ids=$db->value($idsv, 'string');
$search = $this->Search->query("select * from  colleges where college_id!='' and  college_id in ($ids) ");
```

above code is working ok for single string , but if  $idsv =1,2,3,4 its giving result only for 1

Comment: i didn't get your problem? can you elaborate please

Comment: hi i have updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to it like below:-

```
$idsv =$_GET['ids'];
$ids=$db->value($idsv, 'string');
$ids  = "'".implode("','",explode(',',$ids))."'";
$search = $this->Search->query("select * from  colleges where college_id!='' and  college_id in ($ids) ")
```

output:- https://eval.in/716469

Note:- `IN` query works perfectly for `('1','2','3',...)` but takes only first one when comes like this:-`('1,2,3,4')`.

And that's the exact reason why it's failing in your case.

What you shown in comment,do like below:-

```
$idsv =$_GET['ids'];
$ids=$db->value($idsv, 'string');
$ids  = implode("','",explode(',',$ids));
$search = $this->Search->query("select * from  colleges where college_id!='' and  college_id in ($ids) ")
```

Comment: GIVING ERROR  select * from colleges where college_id!='' and college_id in (''41','589'')

Comment: @user3198563  from where this double quotes(`"`) comes inside `()`?.

Comment: YES I ADDED THIS LINE DUE TO SQL INJECTION ATTACK

Comment: if i removed that line code will work fine but sql injection will be there

Comment: can you show the value of `var_dump($ids);`just after this line:- `$ids=$db->value($idsv, 'string');`   and i don't think it will save from SQL Injection

Comment: i am getting '41,589'

Comment: @user3198563  glad to help you